Why is asynchronous response callback working without "return true" in MV3 onmessage handler?
In MV3 docs it is mentioned that we have to "return true" from an onMessage event listener if we want to call our callback function asynchronously. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/messaging#simple
In MV2 I can see this is the case otherwise I get error.

Unchecked runtime.lastError:  The message port closed before a
response was received.

But in MV3 the same code works even though the documentation suggests it shouldn't.
/*contentScript.js*/
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:'getglobals'}, function(response) {
  console.log('The globals are ' + response);//response printed which shouldn't be
})


/*background.js(service worker)*/
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback){
    if (request.msg === 'getglobals') {
        chrome.storage.local.get(['globals'], function(storage) {
            callback(JSON.stringify(storage.globals));
        });
    }
    // return true; Working without this
});

What am I doing wrong(/right) here?

The only explanations are 1) you have a second onMessage listener somewhere else that returns true, 2) you use a library that patches chrome.runtime.onMessage, 3) a bug that I couldn't reproduce e.g. an old background script with "return true" responding to an old content script after you reloaded the extension.

@wOxxOm yea you were right , somewhere in the codebase was hiding a return true inside another onMessage addEventlistener. Due to the way the code is written it will be a bit of a hassle to refactor it. Is there any issue with leaving the return true as it is, even for synchronous callback responses?

Probably, but I'd like to see that synchronous code first.
